# Intersection of two different analytic curves.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I hardly know about Differential Geometry. Recently, I came across the following:

An analytic curve in the plane $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}^1$ of the complex variable $z=x_1+ix_2$ can be represented as a complex-analytic function of a real parameter $z=f(t)$, $\alpha\leq t \leq \beta$, $f'(t) \neq 0$ on $[\alpha,\beta]$. If the analytic curve is located in a domain $D\subset \mathbb{C}$, then a conformal mapping of $D$ into any domain will also yield an analytic curve. If the set of intersection points of two analytic curves is infinite, these analytic curves coincide.

I cannot prove the last line "If the set of intersection points of two analytic curves is infinite, these analytic curves coincide"

Can we prove the same, without using Differential Geometric terms, or, at least "a sort of" simple proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know the identity theorem for analytic functions?

Comment: Yes, but I would I apply it here? Can I find a same parametrization to both of the curves? At the same time, both curves are complex analytic functions of real variable. Can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: not sure what is the issue; you are given two analytic functions $f,g:[0,1] \to \mathbb C$ (where analytic means they have an analytic extension to a small open neighborhood of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb C$ which can be taken same by intersection) st $f(t)=g(t)$ for infinitely many $t \in [0,1]$; the identity theorem says that $f(t)=g(t)$ for all $t$ then since $[0,1]$ is compact so there is an acummulation point for those points

Comment: Can we say that $f(t)=g(t)$ or $f(t)=g(u)$? How can we say that the intersection points have the identical $t$-coordinates on both curves?

Comment: that's a good point - the result is true only locally on the connected components of the limit points since there we can locally invert the functions; we can have something like the upper diameter of a circle prolonged a little both ends and the lower diameter prolonged a little, so they intersect in two disjoint arcs but are not same; so the correct result is that if two (regular) analytic curves intersect in an infinite set, they must have either an arc or two arcs in common, each arc having endpoints from the end points of the two curves; if they are closed then they coincide

Comment: Thank you Conrad for comments!!!! Would you please elaborate it mathematically!!! Since I am finding it difficult to visualize!!

Comment: sketched an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give a sketch of the proof of the following result: let $f,g:[0,1] \to \mathbb C$ regular analytic curves with geometric images $C_1, C_2$. Then if $C_1 \cap C_2$ is infinite, it is either one or two common arcs with the endpoints, being among the endpoints of the two curves.

Taking $C_1$ the upper half of a circle extended a little at both ends and $C_2$ the lower half extended, shows that we can have two arcs, while of course if $C_1 \subset C_2$ say we have one arc. In particular, if the curves are closed, they indeed coincide if they have infinite points in common.

So by hypothesis $f,g$ extend to analytic functions in an open neighborhood $U$ of $[0,1]$ and $f'(z), g'(z)$ do not vanish on $U$ for small enough $U$ by regularity ($f'(t) \ne 0, t \in [0,1]$ means $|f'(t)| \ge \delta >0$, pick neighborhoods of each $t$ where $|f'(z)| \ge \delta/2$ and cover $[0,1]$ by finitely many such etc).

Assume $M=C_1 \cap C_2$ infinite; it is compact hence closed so $M_1=f^{-1}(M)$ is a closed hence compact subset of $[0,1]$ and there is an accumulation point $w$ of $M_1$. As $f'(w) \ne 0$ there is a small open neighborhood $G$ of $w$ for which $f$ is invertible with image some open neighborhood of $f(w)=P \in M$.

Since $f$ is $1-1$ on $G$ there are points $t_n \to w, t_n \in G\cap [0,1], f(t_n)=P_n \in M$ which are distinct so by passing to a subsequence if needed we can assume that there are $s_n \to s \in [0,1], g(s_n)=P_n$ hence $g(s)=P$

Let $K_1, K_2$ the arcs of $C_1, C_2$ determined by $P$ containing the $t_n, s_n$ and belonging to $f(G)$, so $P_n \in K_1 \cap K_2$. Clearly $f^{-1}(K_1)$ is a segment of $[0,1]$ (and if $w \ne 0,1$, $w$ is inside it) while $f^{-1}(K_2)$ is an arc that intersects the real axis in infinitely many points $t_n= f^{-1}(P_n) \to t$. But this means that $f^{-1} \circ g$ is an analytic function in a neighborhood of $s$ that is real at infinitely many points $s_n \in [0,1]$ with an accumulation point $s$ there, hence by the identity theorem, it is real on a segment containing $s$, since $\Im f^{-1} \circ g$ restricted to $[s-\epsilon, s+\epsilon]$ is real analytic so if it has infinitely many zeroes with an acummulation point, is zero (here of course we can have $s=0,1$ when we adjust the interval correspondingly)

Hence we have shown that the two curves coincide on an arc containing $P$ and the proof shows that the arc contains $P$ inside unless $P$ is an endpoint of either curve. But now a connectivity argument immediately shows that we can extend the common arc as long as we do not hit endpoints of either curve at both ends of it, and since those are at most $4$ we can have at most $2$ such arcs, while the example above shows that indeed that situation can occur.

Comment: Conrad, thank you for the proof and your time!!! I will go through the proof and let you know if I do not understand anything!!!! Thank you again for your help!!!

Comment: I will try and clarify any questions; the idea is as noted in earlier comments to apply the identity theorem, but since the parametrizations are different, one needs a change of variables and for that one needs a local inverse which sends a piece of one curve into a real segment and a piece of the other into an analytic arc that crosses said segment infinitely many times and now indeed one can apply the identity theorem to the real analytic imaginary part of a complex analytic function and conclude is zero etc; the reasoning is only local though hence the conclusion is also only local

Comment: Yes, the curves coincides , if they are closed. Does the same holds true, if one is closed and the other is not?

Comment: obviously, the non-closed one will be included in the closed one as the intersection arc must end at its two ends so it is all of it (the proof shows that the intersection cannot end except at original curves ends and the closed one has none)