# Analytic curve except finitely many points.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

It is known that two analytic curves intersecting at infinitely many points are identical ([Intersection of two different analytic curves.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932858/intersection-of-two-different-analytic-curves)). Can we say the same when one curve is analytic and other is also analytic except finitely many points.

**Definition of analytic curve** https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Analytic_curve

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the result quoted about analytic curves is true only if they are both closed, otherwise, they can intersect in up to two arcs with endpoints, being among the endpoints of the original curves (see two slightly extended half-circles); if one is peicewise analytic, take a circle and half a circle plus a diameter, showing the result not to be true even in the closed case (and one can make the second curve smooth by rounding corners, no problem)

Comment: A trivial counter-example would be a straight line compared with the same line which has been bent at some point.

Comment: I completely agree with your comment. Can we say that they at least intersect on a set of positive measure, in sense of Lebesgue.

Comment: When you are answering to a comment, make sure to mention the name of the person with the "at" sign, such as @srm99, so that they get notified of your comment.

Comment: I am sorry @Ruy. I am new here. Will keep your words in my mind, further.

Comment: Please see@Conrad