# Range of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:U \to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function, where $U$ is an open set containing the closed unit disc. Suppose that $|f(z)| \leq 1$, for all $|z|\leq 1$ and $f$ maps infinitely many points of $S^1$ to $S^1$. Can we characterize such functions? (Here $S^1$ means the unit circle).

Note that finite Blaschke products and unimodular multiple of monomials and the constant unimodular function are already in this class. Will there be more?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should be all. Note that the assumptions imply that $f(z)$ has only finitely many zeros (even counting multiplicity) in the closed unit disk.

Comment: Can you kindly explain a little more? @GregMartin

Comment: It is not mentioned that image of $S^1$ is $S^1$. @GregMartin

Comment: $f(S^1)$ is a closed analytic curve and $S^1$ is a closed analytic curve so if they touch at infinitely many points, they must coincide as geometric objects so $f(S^1)=S^1$ - note that $f(S^1)$ may have finitely many critical points but the argument goes through there

Comment: Thanks @Conrad ! Here I have the problem. "$f(S^1)$ may have finitely many critical points", i.e., $f(S^1)$ is again an analytic curve, except finitely many points. But how to tackle these finitely many points, in particular **"if the limit point of the set where $f(S^1)$ agrees with $S^1$ is among such critical points".**

Comment: How I can use the same argument to avoid **those** finitely many points, if the limit point of the intersecting point becomes a critical point. I am sorry that I cannot visualize your comments but it will be of great help, if you provide a little more explanation in this context. @Conrad

Comment: I gave an argument in the question linked where one uses only that one of the curves is regular as that allows a local inverse at a limit point - so here it is enough that $S^1$ is regular, while we need only that $f(S^1)$ is analytic and closed but we do not need it to be regular - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932858/intersection-of-two-different-analytic-curves/3933385#3933385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f=u+iv.$ Then $w(t) = u(e^{it})^2 + v(e^{it})^2$ is a real analytic function on $\mathbb R.$ We are given that $w(t)=1$ for infinitely many $t\in [0,2\pi].$ Thus $w=1$ on set with limit point in $[0,2\pi].$ By the identity principle for real analytic functions, $w\equiv 1.$ This implies $|f(e^{it})|\equiv 1.$ A well known exercise then shows $f=cB_1\cdots B_n,$ where $c$ is a constant of modulus $1,$ and the $B_k$ are Blaschke factors.